# How to set the font-family like a digital clock CSS?

Tags: css

I would like to use a font-family in CSS that the numbers and maybe letters looks like the one in a digital clock. Where can I find a font like this?

Comment: Try this link http://www.1001fonts.com/digital+clock-fonts.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just do this

```
@font-face{
 font-family:'digital-clock-font';
 src: url('put_the_location_to_your_font.ttf or .otf');
}
```

Then apply it to your text `font-family:'digital-clock-font'`

Use **Google** to find a font you like, or try this link for digital clock fonts: http://www.1001fonts.com/digital+clock-fonts.html

Comment: I used this Google you speak of and I ended up here hoping to find a complete answer as SO rarely lets me down.

Comment: This does not work with external urls because of CORS.

Answer (score 29):

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

then...

```
<div style="font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;">12:04PM</div>
```

get...

[image: sample text]

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <div style="font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;">12:04PM</div>
```

Comment: Google allows the `text` parameter, so if you're just pulling this for a the numbers use something like this to improve load times and bandwidth.

`<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron&text=0123456789:AMP' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

I included the colon and "AMP" for AM or PM. You may need to encode the parameters depending on how you're making the request.

Comment: Orbitron isn't a monospaced font though, so if you use it for a clock, then the numbers will jump over the place as they change, because the 1 is thinner than the 0, for example. A monospaced font like VT323 would be better.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to take a look at DS Digital its a font that resembles a digital clock. But Im not too sure how you could use it in CSS.